# With which apply function can I loop a clustering function over a grouped dataframe?

Tags: r, apply, plyr

I have a data frame that contains ETAs for vehicles. The data contains many ETAs for one (actual) arrival, and I want to group the ETAs that should correspond to one arrival together.

My data looks something like this, with `cluster` as my desired result:

```
  vehicle      eta       ...   cluster  
 --------- ------------ ----- --------- 
  car_1     01-11-2017   ...         1  
  car_1     02-11-2017   ...         1  
  car_1     15-11-2017   ...         2  
  horse_3   05-11-2017   ...         1  
  horse_3   12-11-2017   ...         2  
  horse_3   13-11-2017   ...         2
```

I've written a custom function that performs this clustering. The input of the function are the rows for one vehicle, and it returns an array with cluster indices. For example, if I pass it rows 1-3 of my example data, it would output `c(1,1,2)`. So now all I need to do is cycle over all the vehicles in the dataset and apply the function, but that's where I'm stuck.

With `cluster_etas` as my custom clustering function, I know I could do this:

```
# Initialize an empty column
data$cluster <- 0

# Loop over all vehicles and perform clustering
for (i in unique(data$vehicle)) {
    filter_vector <- data$vehicle == i
    data$cluster[filter_vector] <- cluster_etas(data[filter_vector,])
}
```

But I suspect there is a smarter solution that would look something like this, with an `apply`-kind of function filling the blanks:

```
data$cluster <- _____(data = data, by = vehicle, function = cluster_etas)
```

Is there a function that performs this kind of operation? What would it be?

Comment: Looks like `tapply` to me.

Comment: As far as I can see, `tapply` takes only an atomic vector as its input. I actually need to pass the entire row to the clustering function.

Comment: split + lapply ? or if you're open to packages, dplyr's group_by or data.table. Another option could be `?by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution for the problem using the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package. It did require me to change my custom function - previously, the custom function would take a data frame as its argument and extract the required columns, now it takes those columns as arguments directly (which makes for a more general solution anyway).

```
data <- plyr::ddply(data, "vehicle", transform,
                    cluster = cluster_etas(eta, travel_time, ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

`tapply`:
-used to apply a function over subsets of vector

```
str(tapply)
#function (X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE)
```

Explaning the arguments:
`X` is a vector
`INDEX` is a factor or a lists of factors (or something coercible to factors)
`FUN` is a function to be applied
`...` contains other arguments to be passed FUN

Therefore, I believe the solution should be something like
tapply(data$eta, data$vehicle, FUN = ..your function..)

Comment: This would work, except that the custom function requires more data than just the ETA (like the travel time). So it needs the whole row as input, not just one column.

Comment: then I would say the 'apply' family is not the tool you are looking for. More elegant solution can be offered by 'dplyr' and especially 'data.table'.
Unfortunately, I am not a specialist of the latter so let's wait for the solution :)